# rpmbuild renames text files

Tags: linux, bash, rpmbuild

I have a set of packages that host several plain text docs where the names are being appended with ".gz". They remain to be plain text files, but the name of the files is misleading.

Package contents (pre-build):

```
/etc/some-package/config.xml
/opt/some-package/<stuff>
/usr/share/doc/some-package/EULA
/usr/share/doc/some-package/LICENSE.txt
```

SPEC %files section:

```
%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
%config(noreplace) /etc/some-package/config.xml
%docdir /usr/share/doc/some-package
/usr/share/doc/some-package
/opt/some-package
```

Package command:

```
rpmbuild -vv -ba --define "_source_filedigest_algorithm 8" --define 
"_binary_filedigest_algorithm 8" --define "_topdir $WORKSPACE" --
define "_WORKSPACE $WORKSPACE" $WORKSPACE/SPECS/some-package.spec
```

Package contents (post-build):

```
/etc/some-package/config.xml
/opt/some-package/<stuff>
/usr/share/doc/some-package/EULA.gz
/usr/share/doc/some-package/LICENSE.txt.gz
```

Comment: what exactly you want to change ? , just the .gz in names??

Comment: Yes, I'd prefer not to have the files renamed ".gz"